# Analyse by time and other entry

Tags: shell, awk

Got a log, looks like this:

```
2012-02-10 11:00:44.211 connection closed_to host
2012-02-10 11:00:44.598 connection closed_to host
2012-02-10 11:00:45.510 connection closed_to host
2012-02-10 11:00:45.891 connection closed_to host
2012-02-10 11:00:46.111 connection closed_to host
```

Somebody can help me, how can i do an output (using awk) like this?

```
connection closed_to host
11:00:44.211

connection closed_to host
11:00:44.598
```

Comment: You seem to know awk is capable of this. Why haven't you made an attempt to figure out how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply:

```
$ awk '{print $3,$4,$5"\n"$2"\n"}' log
connection closed_to host
11:00:44.211

connection closed_to host
11:00:44.598

connection closed_to host
11:00:45.510

connection closed_to host
11:00:45.891

connection closed_to host
11:00:46.111
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following command:

```
awk '{for(i=3;i<=NF;i++){printf "%s ",$i}; printf "\n"$2"\n\n" }' log
```

`awk` will parse the file line by line.

For each line, `awk`:

1. print every argument from the 3rd to the last
2. print the second argument

Comment: Thanks! A second question, what can I do if i want to see how many errors was in a minute? Like: 2012-02-10 11:00 connection closed to host 4 2012-02-10 11:01 connection closed to host 5

Comment: Your welcome! You should tic my answer to close this thread and ask for help in a new one. You'll have a better visibility.

Answer (score 1):

with the shell:

```
while read date time msg; do echo "$msg"; echo $time; echo; done < log
```